# Laravel Auth::Atempt() sempre retorna false

Tags: laravel, mvc, auth

Tentei fazer a autenticação, mas sempre retorna `false` no método `Auth::attempt()` do Laravel:

```
$prontuario = Input::get('prontuario');
$senha = Input::get('senhas');  
if (Auth::attempt(['prontuario' => $prontuario, 'senha' => $senha]))
{ 
    return Redirect::to('/perfil');
}
else
{
    return Redirect::to('/')->withErrors('Prontuario ou senha inválidos!');
}
```

As senhas inseridas no banco já estao com hash, mas mesmo assim retorna false na condição `if` e não consigo realizar o login. ***O que falta para dar certo?***

Comment: eu fiz uma respostas, mas, eu também precisa ver como está a sua classe `User`, você fez alterações, como ela está? Qual é a versão também do Laravel?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A maneira padrão de fazer autenticação segue um padrão de campo *e-mail* e *senha* (*respectivamente* na tabela ***`users`:*** `email` e `password`), como demonstrado [***no link***](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/authentication#authenticating-users) e [***nesse outro link***](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/authentication#retrieving-the-authenticated-user).

***O código ideal e padrão seria esse***:

```
if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $email, 'password' => $password])) {
     // Authentication passed...
     return redirect()->intended('dashboard');
}
```

Fora desse padrão é possivel também como por exemplo [uma instância da ***classe*** `User`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/authentication#other-authentication-methods):

```
$user = User::find(1);
if ($user)  // encontrou o usuário
{
    Auth::login($user); // autentica o usuário
}
```

faça a pesquisa do usuário trazendo um instância da ***classe*** `User` e passo no método `Auth::login($user)` e também é feita a ***autenticação***.

No seu caso em especifico pude observar que não segue um padrão, então deve utilizar a forma de instância:

```
$prontuario = Input::get('prontuario');
$senha = Input::get('senhas');  

$user = User::where('prontuario', $prontuario)
            ->first(); // buscando um registro desse pontuário

if ($user) // encontrou o usuário
{
   if (Hash::check($senha, $user->senha)) // conferindo senha
   {
       Auth::login($user); // autentica o usuário
   }
   else
   {
       //senha inválida...
   }
}
else
{
   return Redirect::to('/')->withErrors('Prontuario ou senha inválidos!');
}
```

<sub>*Tem um fator também, a autenticação do [laravel](/questions/tagged/laravel) segue um padrão de uma tabela `Users` e de uma classe do [eloquent](/questions/tagged/eloquent) `User`, se houve alteração nisso deve tomar cuidado em alterar em todos as partes para que seu código não quebre, ou seja, é possível a alteração da tabela e do `model` para autenticação, mas, esse código deve refletir nas configurações do [laravel](/questions/tagged/laravel) e isso vai depender da versão.*</sub>

Comment: Perfeito, fiz conforme você passou e deu certo. Cara, to passando muita dor de cabeça com esse esquema de MVC. Não me foi ensinado na faculdade ainda e o professor já está cobrando alta base de conhecimento para o projeto final... Mas Agradeço pela ajuda Virgilio!

Comment: Acho eu que nenhuma faculdade ensina desenvolvimento, é muita teoria e pouca prática, e os professores ainda acham que estão certo, acredito que o sistema de ensino é muito obsoleto. Mas ser didático é o meu lema!